# Disable Firebase Analytics for iOS Debug builds

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, analytics, firebase-analytics

1. are events from the debug builds included in Firebase Analytics reports by default?
2. If they're included, how can I disable Firebase Analytics for the iOS debug builds?

Currently I use the following code to configure the Firebase Analytics:

```
        analyticsEnabled = // Fetch whether the analytics should be enabled
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        // analyticsEnabled = false can be added here for DEBUG builds
        updateDataCollectionConfiguration()
    }

    @objc public static func updateDataCollectionConfiguration() {
        Analytics.setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(analyticsEnabled)
    }
```

I've added a line, where I can force disable analytics for debug builds, but the two questions are still relevant - whether it's needed (is such analytics data even collected for debug builds) and is there any "simpler" way to achieve the same goal, e.g. filter debug-data in the Firebase Console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firebase collects data for debug mode also.

You can check for debug mode using :

```
#ifdef DEBUG
analyticsEnabled = false
updateDataCollectionConfiguration()
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you please also pinpoint the Firebase documentation regarding when it collects or doesn't collect the data?